# `cat & wait` in a script proceeds immediately

Tags: bash, wait

From the command line, typing `cat` waits for user input.
But in the following script, `wait` ignores the background process.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat &
wait
echo "After wait"
```

This script immediately blasts right past the `wait` command.  How can I make `wait` actually wait for the cat command to finish?  I've tried waiting for the specific PID or job number, but the effect is the same.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly? There might be a completely different way to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `cat` is exiting right away, because stdin is not inherited. Try this instead:

```
cat <&0 &
```